# How can I make a header with a line between 2 lines of text?

Tags: header-footer

How can I make a header that looks like this?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That will depend on your document class. With KOMA classes you would use `scrlayer-scrpage`. With the standard classes you can also use `scrlayer-scrpage`, but many people use `fancyhdr`. With memoir you can use class-defined features. Can you tell us what document class you use and what you have so far in a [short example document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility with package `titleps` (which comes with `titlesec`):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath} 
    \usepackage[headheight = 20pt]{geometry} 
    \usepackage{titleps}
    \usepackage{tabularx} 
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \newpagestyle{mine}{%
    \sethead{}{%
    \bfseries\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xr@{}}
   \itshape ARO4080 FEM DOCUMENTATION & \itshape PROJECT \\
   \hline
   \scriptsize\sffamily California State Polytechnic University Pomona &\scriptsize\sffamily Aerospace Engineering
   \end{tabularx}%
   }{}
    \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
    }%
    \pagestyle{mine}
    \begin{document}

        \lipsum[1-8]

    \end{document}
```

[image]